# Something is wrong with my do-while loop involving character position

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

when i run the program the output is just continuous and doesnt end. The goal here is to try and get the + all the way to the left or the right, then print which side won and how many turns it took.

the code is executing now, but it only moves left and right one space from the middle, which makes me think its now with the for loops

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Test {

    public static int MAX_LENGTH = 21;
    public static int MIN_LENGTH = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the length of the rope: ");
        int ropeLength = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (ropeLength < MIN_LENGTH || ropeLength > MAX_LENGTH || ropeLength % 2 != 1) {
            System.out.println("Thats not a valid length (odd number between 5 and 21)");
            System.out.print("Enter the length of the rope: ");
            ropeLength = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        char a;
        String flag = " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < ropeLength / 2; i += 1) {
            flag += "-";
        }
        flag += "+";

        for (int i = 0; i < ropeLength / 2; i += 1) {
            flag += "-";
        }
        System.out.println("");


        do {
            flag = "";
            double rand = Math.random();
            int i;
            if (rand > 0.5) {

                for (i = 0; i < (ropeLength / 2) - 1; i++) {
                    flag += "-";
                    }

                flag += "+";

                for (i = 0; i < (ropeLength / 2) + 1; i++) {
                    flag += "-";
                }
                System.out.println( flag );
            }
            if (rand < 0.5) {

                for (i = 0; i < (ropeLength / 2) + 1; i++) {
                    flag += "-";
                    }

                flag += "+";

                for (i = 0; i < (ropeLength / 2) - 1; i++) {
                    flag += "-";
                   }
                   System.out.println( flag );
                } 

        } while (flag.charAt(1) != '+' || flag.charAt(ropeLength) != '+');

        if (flag.charAt(0) == '+') {
            System.out.println("\nLeft side wins!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nRight side wins!");
        }    
        System.out.println("It took steps");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does continuous output look like?

Comment: ----+---------+--------+---- etc

Answer (score 2):

You need to pay attention to the position of the flag.  Currently you only put the flag one position to the left or right of the center.  You might want to pull your flag printing method into a helper method to ease readability and make it clearer what you need to keep track of.

Once you replace your three printing methods with calls to this method, it should become clearer what you need to keep track of and pass as parameters in order to get everything working.

Something like this should get you started:

```
public static void printFlag(int ropeLength, int flagPosition) {
    for (int i = 0; i < flagPosition; i += 1) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.print("+");

    for (int i = flagPosition + 1; i < ropeLength; i += 1) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Note: Using a `StringBuilder` instead of a bunch of `print()` calls is probably a good idea, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with the logic in your code.

1) In your do-while loop you always just keep appending to flag. This means that for every iteration your flag just gets bigger, it doesn't actually move the `+` that you have in there. You can have a temporary variable called 'nextState' to generate the next state and then set flag equal to it at the end.

Code:

```
String nextState = "";
if (rand > 0.5) {
    for (i = 0; i < (ropeLength / 2) - 1; i++) {
        nextState += "-";
    }
    nextState += "+";
    for (i = 0; i < (ropeLength / 2) + 1; i++) {
        nextState += "-";
    }
    flag = nextState;
    System.out.println(flag);
}
```

2) You are checking if `flag.charAt(1)=='+'` and `flag.charAt(ropeLength)=='+'`. Since arrays have a 0 based index this is incorrect, you actually need `0` and `ropeLength-1` respectively. (I do note that you did it correctly below the do-while loop).

3) The problem with your do-while loop is that if you correct errors 1 and 2, you will definitely move the + to the left and to the right, however you will NEVER be able to move it to position `0` (all the way left) or position `ropeLength-1` (all the way right) with your current logic. Something like this can be done and you can similarly do it for the other if.

```
if (rand > 0.5) {
  i = 0;
  while (i + 1 < flag.length() && flag.charAt(i + 1) != '+') {
    nextState += "-";
    i++;
  }
  nextState += "+";
  i++;
  while (i < flag.length()) {
    nextState += "-";
    i++;
  }
  flag = nextState;
}
```

4) You initialize `flag = " ";` but you just want `flag = "";` (an empty string) as flag only contains `-`'s and a `+`.

5) `while (flag.charAt(0) != '+' || flag.charAt(ropeLength - 1) != '+');` is incorrect. It shold be `&&` because your original statement will ALWAYS be true and the loop will never end. Your original statement will only be false if there is a `+` in the begining and in the end which is impossible.

6) Not really an issue but with your `if (rand > 0.5)` you could have used an if-else instead of two `if`'s. If rand is exactly equal to 0.5 your code does nothing. Since you have to count steps you need to change one of them to `rand <= 0.5` or `rand >= 0.5` or just use an if-else.

Once you fix these problems. You are good to go. Great effort!

Comment: I need to incorporate Camerons stuff into this answer. I did it for length = 5. and I didn't pay attention that you were also moving the `+` incorrectly. I'm fixing it.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: You should never get a -1 index out of bounds error as you never decrease i. but this is the closest code I could come up with without changing the way you approach this problem. I'm going to edit this question more. SPOILER: http://pastebin.com/NnFBJGsP

Comment: Since this loop will possibly never end for large enough input, using an `int` for step is probably a bad idea. I should use a `long` or even better a BigInteger instead. Also, StringBuilder and StringBuffer are ideal data type here instead of String for nextState as you do a lot of string appends and this way is all very memory inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the last line, from:

`while (flag.charAt(1) != '+' || flag.charAt(ropeLength) != '+');`

to

`while (flag.charAt(0) != '+' && flag.charAt(ropeLength) != '+');`

Using `||` means that only ONE of those conditions has to be true, and since you are using a while loop, you're saying that if the first position is not equal to `+` OR the last position is not equal to `+` then you want the loop to continue.

---

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:695)
 at test.Test.main(Test.java:67)
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 1):

You never reset your flag at the start of each iteration

and you need the && operator as knoight says

you need something like:

```
do {
flag = "";
... your existing code

 } while ( (flag.charAt(1) != '+') && (flag.charAt(ropeLength) != '+') );
```

it seems like your flag is going to randomly jump around with the fixes i've proposed above.  perhaps you want to simply move the flag left or right one spot on each iteration?

you can do that like this:

```
int flagpos = (ropeLength / 2)+1;
do {
    flag = "";
    double rand = Math.random();
    int i;
    if (rand > 0.5) {
        flagpos++;
    else
        flagpos--;
    for (i = 0; i < flagpos - 1; i++) 
        flag += "-";
    flag += "+";
    for (i = flagpos + 1; i < ropeLength ; i++) 
        flag += "-";

        System.out.println( flag );
    } while (flag.charAt(1) != '+' || flag.charAt(ropeLength) != '+');
```

Comment: ok that worked, but now the + is only moving back and forth 1 space to the left and right continuously. thank you

Comment: ---+-----
-----+---
-----+---
---+-----
---+-----
---+-----
-----+---
---+-----
-----+---
---+-----
---+-----
---+-----

Comment: hm didnt turn out like i thought. all of those are on top of one another though which is good. Now the only problem is it isnt moving any more left or right, just stuck on those 2

Comment: I don't think the loop is actually shifting them to the right or left at all. You're repeatedly setting the '+' either to the left or right of the mid point, but it's the same location every time.  You need to keep track of where the last position of the '+' was at, and then shift it left/right based on that.

Comment: Since you already keep track of flagpos you should also do while( flagpos != 1 && flagpos != ropeLength ) and use the constructed flag just for output. Though not really false, the first for would be semantically better, i believe, as for( i = 1; i < flagpos; i++ ). The second for should be for( i = flagpos + 1; i <= ropeLength; i++ ).

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier the follow will work.

```
    do {
       flag = "";
       //do stuff
    } while (flag.charAt(1) != '+' && flag.charAt(ropeLength-1) != '+');
```

Problem is your flipping a coin to move the rope and the larger the rope length the smaller the chance you will ever reach the end.